# Cutted cube with PyQt5

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, pyopengl, python-3.9

I'm working with python3.9-64, I need to create a 3d cube then I followed this [tutorial](https://nrotella.github.io/journal/first-steps-python-qt-opengl.html),
I divided the program in more files, I use PyQt5 but the tutorial uses PyQt4, I changed the modules which contain the calsses(example: PyQt4 has Gui.QMainWindow, PyQt5 has QtWidgets.QMainWindow)

this are the file I have

core.py

```
cubeVtxList = [
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
        
cubeClrList = [
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
        
cubeIdxList = [
    0, 1, 2, 3,
    3, 2, 6, 7,
    1, 0, 4, 5,
    2, 1, 5, 6,
    0, 3, 7, 4,
    7, 6, 5, 4 ]
```

GLWidget.py

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.GLU as glu
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import numpy as np
from core import *
    
class GLWidget(QGLWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        QGLWidget.__init__(self)
        
    def initializeGL(self):
        self.qglClearColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        self.initGeometry()
        self.rotX = 0.0
        self.rotY = 0.0
        self.rotZ = 0.0
    
    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        aspect = width / float(height)
        glu.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    
    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glPushMatrix()
        gl.glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -50.0)    # third, translate cube to specified depth
        gl.glScale(20.0, 20.0, 20.0)       # second, scale cube
        gl.glRotate(self.rotX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotate(self.rotY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotate(self.rotZ, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        gl.glTranslate(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
        
        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertVbo)
        gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, self.colorVbo)
        
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_QUADS, len(self.cubeIdxArray), gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, self.cubeIdxArray)
        
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        
        gl.glPopMatrix()
    
    def initGeometry(self):
        self.cubeVtxArray = np.array(cubeVtxList)
        self.vertVbo = vbo.VBO(np.reshape(self.cubeVtxArray, (1, -1)).astype(np.float32))
        self.vertVbo.bind()
        self.cubeClrArray = np.array(cubeClrList)
        self.colorVbo = vbo.VBO(np.reshape(self.cubeClrArray, (1, -1)).astype(np.float32))
        self.colorVbo.bind()
        self.cubeIdxArray = np.array(cubeIdxList)
        
    def setRotX(self, val):
        self.rotX = val

    def setRotY(self, val):
        self.rotY = val

    def setRotZ(self, val):
        self.rotZ = val
```

MWindow.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QSlider, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from GLWidget import GLWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class MWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('titolo')
        self.glWidget = GLWidget(self)
        self.initGui()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(20)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.glWidget.updateGL)
        self.timer.start()
    
    def initGui(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        gui_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(gui_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        gui_layout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        sliderX = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sliderX.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: self.glWidget.setRotX(val))
        sliderY = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sliderY.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: self.glWidget.setRotY(val))
        sliderZ = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sliderZ.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: self.glWidget.setRotZ(val))
        gui_layout.addWidget(sliderX)
        gui_layout.addWidget(sliderY)
        gui_layout.addWidget(sliderZ)
```

Main.py

```
from MWindow import MWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
    
def Main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mw = MWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The result is supposed to be a cube that I can move with the sliders, but I get a cutted cube like in the following picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default [`dtype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes) is *float*. When creating and indexing a buffer, you must use an integral datatype that corresponds to the type identifier in the draw call. In your case the specified type is `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`. Therefore the datatype must be *uint32*:

<s>`self.cubeIdxArray = np.array(cubeIdxList)`</s>

```py
self.cubeIdxArray = np.array(cubeIdxList, dtype=np.uint32)
```

---

The last parameter of `glVertexPointer` si not the vertex buffer offset. It is the offset into the buffer objects data store. You have to bind the proper buffer specifying the attribute:

<s>`gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertVbo)`</s>
<s>`gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, self.colorVbo)`</s>

```py
self.vertVbo.bind()
gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
self.colorVbo.bind()
gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
```

Comment: @Linus I've spotted another issue in your code. I've extended the answer.

Comment: @Linus So there is another issue. What "does not work"? Has anything changed?

Comment: No, it keep being the same cube in the picture

Comment: @Linus Sorry that cannot be the case. Something must change, when you do the changes as I suggested. (Perhaps it is still not correct, but it must be different)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the first entry in cubeClrList in your core.py from

```
cubeClrList = [
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
```

to

```
cubeClrList = [
# v change this value
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
```